# Document Acknowledgement w/ anonymous users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pdf

We have a business need for having employees read documents and acknowledge that they have read them (specifically PDF, but possible other types in the future).  We would like to keep track of who has read the documents in a SharePoint List.

We also need the ability to send a document/link to a user that is off the network and allow them to acknowledge that they have read the document. The acknowledgement is simply their name and email address.

I have considered the option of adding a submit button to the PDF that submits the data to a web service that then updates a SP list. I'm wondering if there is something already available or another option through SP Online that may help?  Is there another option I'm not aware of? A way to post data to a SP online list?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need PDF form to SharePoint integration to save data in the list. Without it you can only setup library to accept mails and save attachments as files in library.

To find integration options just google "pdf sharepoint" there is bunch of reliable 3rd party programs.

Best regards,